# Opening a zip folder within another zip folder

Tags: python, zip

I have some files in a .zip folder that is contained within yet another .zip folder. I can get into the first .zip folder, but was having trouble getting to the files in the second. Here is my code so far:

```
first_zip = '/path/to/zip1.zip'
if not zipfile.is_zipfile(first_zip):
    print 'not a zip file'
else:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(first_zip, 'r') as z1:
        second_zip = os.path.join(z1.filename[:-4], 'second_zip.zip')
        with zipfile.ZipFile(second_zip, 'r') as z2:
            for file in z2.namelist:
                do_stuff()
```

So the general idea here is to run some function for each of the files in the second .zip folder, which is nested in the first .zip folder. The error I get is:

```
IOError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: 
'/path/to/zip1/second_zip.zip'
```

How can I work to remedy this, and access the data in these files?

Comment: It's probably a good idea to add the programming language you're using as a tag.

Comment: Where's the `zipfile` module you're referencing when you invoke `zipfile.is_zipfile()`?